# Login - Comparing user input with database

Tags: .net, ms-access, netbeans, odbc

I have been googling for a while now and I still can't find the answer to my question..
which is: I want to know if there's a method or a way to get the database's value and then compare it...I'm not really sure how to explain it..so I guess I'll show you what I got so far for my code. BTW Im using netbean to make this program and im using odbc database (mircosoft access). Im also using try catch in the code but idk how to make it show..

The program below doesn't really work the way I want it too..since I'm having problems comparing. 
Thanks in advance.

```
if(request.getParameter("username")!=null && request.getParameter("username") !=""
        && request.getParameter("password")!=null && request.getParameter("password")!=""){ 

    String user = request.getParameter("username").toString();
    String pass = request.getParameter("password").toString();

    String check = "SELECT AccountType FROM Testing WHERE Username='"+user+"' AND Password ='"+pass+"'";
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(check); 
    String info = rs.getString(check); // trying to get the AccountType and store it into a string

    while(rs.next()){
        if(info != null && info !=""){  //checks to see if the account exist in the database                
            if(info.equals("Admin")){ //checks to see if AccountType is "Admin"
                    response.sendRedirect("AdminConsole.jsp"); 
            }else
                response.sendRedirect("UserConsole.jsp");
        }else
            response.sendRedirect("ErrorPage2.jsp");
    }
}else
    response.sendRedirect("ErrorPage.jsp");

connection.close();
```

}

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: You should never store passwords in plain text.

Comment: to solve the above mentioned issues;
- Use parameterized queries to prevent SQL injection
- Store a hash (MD5 for instance) of the password to compare against.

Without trying to be negative, this code is seriously dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

Please, please don't do this. You should not execute the SQL from within code, nor should you store passwords in plain text. What you should do is invoke a parameterized procedure that takes username/password as arguments and then returns roles (or whatever else you want). Password should still be hashed at a minimum.

Something like this: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/87556

In MS Access the Stored Procedure is referred to as a stored query:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140021(v=office.10).aspx

Relevant parts:

Proc:

```
create procedure ValidateUserLogin
  @UserName varchar(30)
  , @Password varchar(30)
as
begin
  if exists (select * from UsersTable as ut
    where ut.UserName = @UserName AND ut.Password = @Password)
    select 1;
  else
    select 0;
end
```

Class

```
private bool IsValidatedUser( string username, string password ) {
  try {
    bool rv = false;

    using ( SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection( connectionString ) ) {
      using ( SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand() ) {
        con.Open();

        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "ValidateUserLogin";

        cmd.Parameters.Add( "@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30 ).Value = username;
        cmd.Parameters.Add( "@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30 ).Value = password;

        rv = Convert.ToBoolean( cmd.ExecuteScalar() );

        con.Close();
      }
    }

    return rv;
  } 
catch ( Exception ex ) {
    // Log errors
    throw;
  }
}
```

Comment: oh ok ill try out these methods. I'm still new at this stuff so ill just do trial and error. Thanks for all the replies.